# My question has been marked as a dupe but isn't one

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

I'm complaining about the "duping" of this one which I posted at Space Exploration, last night:

[Wouldn't it be better to leave Earth less dramatically?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24792/wouldnt-it-be-better-to-leave-earth-less-dramatically)

The people who marked it as a dupe are wrong, possibly in bad faith. Does anyone agree (as explained by me at the top) and have the power to un-duplicate it?

It's OK to not like a question. It is not OK to mark something as a dupe when it isn't one. FWIW 2 people have voted down and 2 have voted up. 176 have viewed it.

Comment: I agree that your question isn't clearly a dupe of either of those, so I have closed it with a different reason.

Comment: Hahaha.  Ok now closed by a mod (for a reason I understand).  I prefer that to it being marked as a dupe when it isn't one.

Comment: Unfortunately, the blanket off-topic description box says that by default and you can't change it. You can see my explanation in the comments.

Comment: Ah... fair enough.  Will delete 2nd comment.  Shame. I wanted some more feedback.

Comment: If folks are willing to continue to work it out with you, you can still use the chat rooms I created on the comment threads. I just think the discussion is getting too long for Stack Exchange Q&A.

Comment: Ok... thanks. Makes perfect sense!